# Android app cannot be updated on new version of Play Store due to configuration errors

Tags: android, google-play, google-tv, android-market-filtering

Apologies for the wall of text. My company uses a single listing for multiple apks on the play store as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467464/multiple-apks-single-listing-of-app-for-google-tv-and-android-phone-tablet-on-p). The package name used for both apks is com.company.xyz. Our GTV app's current version is 1203010007 and phone/tablet app's current version is 1714010016.

We want to release an update (1714010017) to our Android phone app. I am able to upload the phone apk on the old version of the play store but when I try to submit the same on the new version of the play store, it throws the errors below. These errors have been showing up for a while when I switch to the new version of the play store.

*This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):*

All devices that might receive version 1714010016 would receive version 1714010017.
A device with API levels in range 12+ is eligible to receive version 1203010007, which is optimized for higher API levels, but actually receives version 1714010017 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when

- Screen layouts containing any of [normal, large, xlarge] and
- Native platforms containing any of [armeabi] and
- Features containing all of
  [android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN,
  com.google.android.TV].

A device upgrading from API levels in range 8-11 to API levels in range 12+ would become eligible to receive version 1203010007, which is optimized for higher API levels, but would actually receive version 1714010017 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when

- Screen layouts containing any of [normal, large, xlarge] and
- Native platforms containing any of [armeabi] and
- Features containing all of [android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, com.google.android.TV].

A device with API levels in range 12+ is eligible to receive version 1203010007, which is optimized for higher API levels, but actually receives version 1714010016 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when

- Screen layouts containing any of [normal, large, xlarge] and
- Native platforms containing any of [armeabi] and
- Features containing all of [android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, com.google.android.TV].

A device upgrading from API levels in range 8-11 to API levels in range 12+ would become eligible to receive version 1203010007, which is optimized for higher API levels, but would actually receive version 1714010016 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when

- Screen layouts containing any of [normal, large, xlarge] and
- Native platforms containing any of [armeabi] and
- Features containing all of
  [android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN,
  com.google.android.TV].

**TL;DR:** Some devices are eligible to receive the wrong listing of the apk because of conflicts in app version code or API level.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

The new version of the Google Play Store goes into effect on April 15th, 2013 after which I can no longer use the old version for uploading updates. Is it better to go with separate listings for GTV and Android phone/tablet at this point?

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SupportedFilters you will see that:

"An APK that requires a higher API level must have a higher version code."

So this implies you will need to change your version release strategy accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We chose to go with different apk listing for mobile and GTV.